# PostgreSQL — considerations when adding new values to rows with a long-running migration

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, alter-table

I have a table of ten columns containing 370 million rows and I need to add six new columns to it. Some new columns will take null values, others will be defined with `NOT NULL DEFAULT`. After altering the table I'll start a long-running migration that will fill the new columns with relevant values. Some rows will also be updated by the main application while the migration is running, filling the new column values as well as changing the old column values. After the migration completes I will drop the `DEFAULT` clauses and add indexes containing these new columns.

Postgres version is 12.5 and the default values will be non-volatile, so adding the defaults shouldn't be a problem.

My questions are:

1. Is there anything I should consider to optimize the data migration? For example, should I try to migrate the rows in the order that they were inserted, would that be more efficient than updating them while iterating by a foreign key relation?
2. As far as I know, autovacuum is enabled for the table. Should the migration affect vacuum policies? Should autovacuum be postponed until the migration completes, for example?
3. Do I understand correctly that it would be more efficient to build the indexes on the new columns when all the rows are updated rather than creating the indexes right away, assuming I don't need the new indexes until the migration is finished?

Comment: If the columns are created with nonvolatile defaults already supplied, then why is any migration needed?

Comment: @jjanes The defaults are supplied so that the column types match the non-nullable field types in application code during object-relational mapping and are basically dummy values. Only after the migration is complete will the application utilize the new fields.

Comment: So the default will be some kind of magic value which indicates that that row has not yet been migrated?  Usually you would NULL as the magic value, but I guess there are reasons you can't.

Comment: I don't think there can be much of an answer to this, as it depends on your goal.  Are you trying to complete the migration as fast as possible, or with as little impact on the production processes as possible (and would that be due to row locks, or resource contention, and which resource?), or with as little bloat as possible, or disturbing the existing physical order (aka "clustering") of rows as little as possible?

Comment: @jjanes You're right, I should have specified my goals. I aim to complete the migration as fast as possible. Second priority would be to create as little bloat as possible, but only if it doesn't severely impact he speed of the migration.

Comment: @jjanes The defaults are just placeholders for successful deserialization and mapping into domain entities, the hold no meaning and are only there to comply to the desired schema with non-nullable values.